# How can I improve and get to know the game?

Tags: learning

I'm just starting at chess and I would like to understand better the game itself , and if possible some tips on how to get better.

Comment: Chess.com is a good place to start as they have daily puzzles and tactic trainers

Comment: Hi 123, this question is a little bit too broad right now.  Can you focus your question more to focus on either learning rules or improving?  Stack Exchange works better with questions that have definitive answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chess is a game of strategy and tactics. Each player commands an army of 16 chessmen --- pawns and other pieces (the king, queen, bishops, knights, and rooks).

A well-played chess game has three stages. In the opening, the players bring out their forces in preparation for combat. The middlegame begins as the players maneuver for position and carry out attacks and counterattacks. The final stage is the endgame when, with fewer pawns and pieces left on the board, it is safer for the kings to come out and join the final battle.

As play proceeds, each player will capture some of the opponent's men; often, the capturing pieces are immediately recaptured. As long as the piece a player gives up is generally equal to the piece he gets in return, we say the players are exchanging. If you unintentionally place a piece where it can be captured without getting a piece of equal value in return, we say that you put that piece en prise. (This is a French term that literally means "in take.") Sometimes a player may place a piece en prise in order to trick an opponent. If the opponent captures the offered man, it may leave him open to attack.

You're Ready to Go!

It's time for you to take a look at these ten tips to help you learn some simple ways to win more games:

1 Look at your opponent's move.
2 Make the best possible move.
3 Have a plan.
4 Know what the pieces are worth.
5 Develop quickly and well.
6 Control the center.
7 Keep your king safe.
8 Know when to trade pieces.
9 Think about the endgame.
10 Always be alert.

Don't rush. Take your time and be sure to study the examples carefully

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner, certain areas are much more important than others:

- Learn the opening principles. You *might* look at some standard openings, but don't go too deep, just know the concepts
- Study the simple endgame mates (with a queen, with a rook, with two bishops)
- Learn how to promote a single pawn, learn how to defend against a single pawn (rule of the square...)
- Know the typical beginner opening traps. Don't *use* them, just don't fall for them
- Tactics, tactics, tactics: Forks, pins, discovered checks, mating patterns...
- Learn *basic* positional principles (fight for the center, open lines, doubled pawns, isolated pawns, don't castle into the attack, opposite-colored bishops are drawish, knights are better than bishops in closed positions and vice versa...)

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes a man perfect.

Play more games and eventually you will see yourself improving from the mistakes you make.

Chess.com seems to be the best source to play online which I 've seen in recent times.